# Discord.net cannot receive voice data

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to listen for voice data from a user within same voice channel the bot is in. I have an infinite loop, where I try to read voice data from `AudioInputStream`. The problem is that every time I use `TryReadFrame` method, it returns `false`. And I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
    private async Task ReadAsync() // This method is called only once, when bot found a voice stream
    {
        while (AudioStream.CanRead)
        {
            if (!AudioStream.TryReadFrame(default, out var frame))
            {
                //Log.Debug("No data found for user {User}.", User.Username);
                
                await _writer!.StandardInput.BaseStream.WriteAsync(_silenceBuffer);
                await _writer!.StandardInput.BaseStream.FlushAsync();

                continue;
            }
            
            Log.Debug("Frame read from user {User}", User.Username);
        
            // You probably don't need this part.
        }
        
        Log.Debug("Reading voice data of {User} finished.", User.Username);
    }
```

I`ve read somewhere that Discord won't send any voice data unless bot sends at last one audio packet. So here is how I connect to a voice channel and do that:

```
        _audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();

        await using var outputStream = _audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed);

        try
        {
            await outputStream.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 0, 10);
            await outputStream.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e, "Failed to send handshake voice data.");
        }
```

I hope that someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: I simply decided to use different library.